# Disable Android text field suggestions

Tags: android, autocomplete

In a web page running on an Android browser (on a Galaxy Nexus), is it possible to disable the feature that suggests words (in a box above the keyboard) and underlines them as you type?

[image: Sample screen]

I tried `autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off"`, but it had no effect.

Comment: That's a user setting; it's up to the user to enable or disable it.

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: I was hoping to disable it in fields where it's not relevant (e.g. you're not typing dictionary words).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In a web page running on an Android browser (on a Galaxy Nexus), is it
>   possible to disable the feature that suggests words (in a box above
>   the keyboard)

No

> and underlines them as you type?

No

Those are user preferences and moreover if the user bought a keyboard app, it can have its own setting to auto-complete.

Answer (score 4):

In experiencing the same issue I did some digging and discovered it is a bug in Chrome for Android. Those HTML 5 attributes are intended to do what you are looking for but are not properly supported in Chrome for Android(they do work for iOS). It appears to just recently have been fixed and hopefully should be released in an update soon.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=303883&q=autocorrect&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Also feel free to Star the issue to help boost the ranking...